# Bundle install ignores pg gem

Tags: postgresql, bundle-install

When I type, "gem install pg", I get a message that the gem is installed along with the documenation.

But when I put "gem 'pg'" in the gemfile, and type "bundle install", it says that the bundle is complete.  However if I type "bundle show pg", it says that it cannot find 'pg' in the current bundle.  Accordingly, a command  like "rake db:create:all", gives back, "no such file to load -- pg"

I am running on Ubuntu 11.04, Rails 3.0.11 and ruby 1.9.2.

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this by deleting my Gemfile.lock and then running bundle install again. I am not sure why this works.

Comment: Because 'Bundler remembers the exact versions it installed in Gemfile.lock.' -http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-update.1.html

Answer (score 1):

How I solved this problem:
I found the string in Gemfile.lock, in "GEM" section:

> pg (0.15.1-x86-mingw32)

But I work on x64 OS (Windows 7 64), and "gem list" shows me "pg" gem as:

> pg (0.15.1 x64-mingw32)

So, I replaced the string in Gemfile.lock to:

> pg (0.15.1-x64-mingw32)

And my project works!

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, I had to install these two devel libraries

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql
sudo apt-get install pgadmin3
bundle install
```

thats worked for me :)